# Why I obtain "cannot find -ljvm" error message when I try to compile a C project?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have the following problem compiling a C project into Linux Ubuntu 12.04 shell

I first execute:

```
make clean
```

and it work well

Thene I execute:

```
make all
```

and then I obtain the following error message:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/default/jre/lib/i386/client -o "atmosfs"  ./bbfs.o ./cimeparser.o ./settingsparser.o ./log.o ./hashtable.o ./jniHelper.o ./decodeError.o   -lpthread -lxml2 -lfuse -ljvm -lrt -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [atmosfs] Errore 1
```

As you can see the error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
```

What can I do to try to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: That question has been asked before. Try googling it.

Comment: Show us the content of your Makefile, first.